# keep track of presence

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to find a way how to keep track of students lessons presence (and absence). The main problem is that they pay in advance a series of 10 or 30 lessons, and once is done the can pay a new serie.

What is the best solution of doing that?

I will have two tables that looks sort of like that

### presence

id
user_id
lesson_id

### absence

id
user_id
lesson_id
reason

I was thinking on both tables to add a boolean column that will be true when the series is done (sort of bookmark). Then when I access the database my query will, for every user_id, count how many records there are after the last true value (if any).

Doesn't sound like a good strategy to me but I can't find another way.

Comment: I would have just 1 table (attendance) so what if absence reason is redundant in most cases - if you are really worried about space have an absence code and another table to hold that code meaning. I have no idea what a serie is in this context but if lessons belong to serie then another table(s) holding serie to lesson relationship may be appropriate.

Comment: thanks for your input! With a serie I mean that every student pay for 10 or 30 lessons, and once he has no more lessons left he can subscribe for another 10 or 30. (My apologies for the confusion). So I have to keep track only for the newly payed lessons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a **User_Lesson_Series** table:

#### User_Lesson_Series

- id
- user_id
- number_of_lessons_paid_for
- payment_date
- number_of_lessons_remaining

Secondly, the suggestion made by P.Salmon of having an **Attendance** table (rather than a **Presence** table and an **Absence** table) is a good one:

#### Attendance

- id
- lesson_id
- user_lesson_series_id
- absence_flag
- absence_reason

When inserting a record into **User_Lesson_Series** for the first time, set **number_of_lessons_remaining** to the same value as **number_of_lessons_paid_for**.

Every time you record a student's attendance (or non-attendance) in the **Attendance** table, you should also update that record's parent row in the **User_Lesson_Series** table, decrementing **number_of_lessons_remaining** by 1.

If a **User_Lesson_Series** record has **number_of_lessons_remaining** = 0, then you should not permit any more **Attendance** records to be written out for that **user_lesson_series_id**. Instead, you should require a new user lesson series to be paid for, necessitating a new **User_Lesson_Series** record to be generated.

Subsequent **Attendance** records will have the **user_lesson_series_id** of that new **User_Lesson_Series**.

Comment: Thank you! Couple of questions: in adding "number_of_lessons_remaining" we are not sort of duplicating data? (because it can be extrapolated with the rest of the data). Also, is gonna be a good idea to have a query that can recheck the number_of_lessons_remaining counter? And lastly, absence_flag is intended as a bool value?

Comment: Hi Patch, yes you could get rid of the number_of_lessons_remaining if you're confident you can always derive it from Attendance, but that depends on requirements (perhaps students are given an extra bonus lesson sometimes that they don't have to pay for, meaning the application must increment number_of_lessons_remaining...) And absence_flag would be a boolean or yes/no thing, that's right.

Comment: Thanks Nabav! so I can replace number_of_lessons_remaining with an expired_flag that that is true when no more lessons are left, right? I originally divided presence/absence because not all absences will trigger a lesson count (depends on the reason code). I can make it in one single table and have extra filtering, but is that a good idea?

Comment: You should still have Attendance as a single table; however, if not all absences are going to decrease the lessons-remaining count, then I would strongly recommend having the number_of_lessons_remaining attribute on User_Lesson_Series. After writing out an Attendance record, the application should (depending on certain values on the Attendance record it's writing out) either decrement number_of_lessons_remaining or leave number_of_lessons_remaining alone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably make this one student_lesson table:

```
student_lesson (student_id, lesson_id, status_id, absence_reason)
```

plus a status table for the statuses Open, Attended, Absent.

Once a student pays for the next n lessons, you create n rows in the student_lesson table. And when a lesson has passed, you update the status to either Attended or Absent.

With an index on student_id and status_id you can quickly see how many Open lessons a student still has.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Never thought of "opening slots" in a table! In my case I don't think it will work as I may have some absences that are not counted as lesson and it might happen that a teacher has to record a presence even if there are no lessons left